# MYSQL query is taking forever

Tags: mysql

I have a report that needs running to satisfy our reporting requirements for a government body. The report is supposed to return the study load for each student in each module for a given period of time.

For example the report needs to return the students enrolled in a given module for a given intake in a given year and semester, with a census date (a government specified date that after which the student is liable for the cost of the unit even if they withdraw)

So I've written this mysql query

```
 SELECT 
   e.enrolstudent AS '313', 
   (SELECT c.ntiscode FROM course c WHERE c.courseid=ec.courseid)  AS '307', 
   e.startdate as '534',
   'AOU' as '333',
   m.mod_eftsl as '339',
   e.enrolmod as '354',
   e.census_date as '489',
   m.diciplinecode as '464',
   (CASE 
      WHEN m.mode = 'Face to Face' THEN 1
      WHEN m.mode = 'Online' THEN 2 
      WHEN m.mode = 'RPL' THEN 5 
      ELSE 3      
   END) AS '329',
   'A6090' as '477',
   up.citizen AS '358',
   vf.maxcontribute as '392',
   vf.studentstatus as '490',
   vf.total_amount_charged as '384',
   vf.amount_paid as '381',
   vf.loan_fee as '529',
   u.chessn as '488',
   m.workexp as '337',
   '0' as '390',
   m.sumwinschool as '551',
   vf.help_debt as '558'
FROM 
   enrolment e
   INNER JOIN enrolcourse AS ec ON ec.studentid=e.enrolstudent
   INNER JOIN vetfee AS  vf ON vf.userid=e.enrolstudent
   INNER JOIN users AS  u ON u.userid = e.enrolstudent
   INNER JOIN users_personal AS  up ON up.userid = e.enrolstudent
   INNER JOIN module AS m ON m.modshortname = e.enrolmod
WHERE 
      e.online_intake in (select oi.intakecode from online_intake oi where STR_TO_DATE(oi.censusdate,'%d-%m-%Y') > '2015-07-01' and STR_TO_DATE(oi.censusdate,'%d-%m-%Y') < '2015-09-31') AND 
      e.enrolstudent NOT LIKE '%onlinetutor%' AND 
      e.enrolstudent NOT LIKE '%tes%' AND 
      e.enrolstudent NOT like '%student%' AND 
      e.enrolrole = 'student' 
ORDER BY e.enrolstudent;"
```

It seems to hang, I've left it running for an hour with no result. There's only 10189 records in th enrolment table, 1538 in enrolcourse,650 in module. I don't think its the number of records, I'm guessing I've just constructed my query wrong, first time using joins (other than natural). Any ideas or tips in improving this would be greatly appreciated.

```
select count(*) from enrolment;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    10189 |
+----------+

select count(*) from enrolcourse;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     1538 |
+----------+

select count(*) from vetfee;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     1538 |
+----------+

select count(*) from users;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     1249 |
+----------+

select count(*) from users_personal;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      941 |
+----------+

select count(*) from module;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      650 |
```

Here's the results of the EXPLAIN

```
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | m     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   691 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | up    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   987 | Using join buffer               |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | u     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  1180 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | ec    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  1607 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | e     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 10629 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | vf    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 10959 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | oi    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    42 | Using where                     |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | c     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    23 | Using where                     |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: How many records do each of your tables have?

Comment: Add indexes on all the columns used for the joins.

Comment: What does [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) show?

Comment: # of Records in each table added

Comment: @PeterKelly - Do you have any ability to alter the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of those correlated subqueries.  Use a join instead.

Also, use `BETWEEN` to reduce one `STR_TO_DATE` call

Finally, you should look at a way of eliminating all those `LIKE` calls.

```
SELECT 
    e.enrolstudent AS '313', 
    c.ntiscode AS '307', 
    e.startdate as '534',
   'AOU' as '333',
    m.mod_eftsl as '339',
    e.enrolmod as '354',
    e.census_date as '489',
    m.diciplinecode as '464',
    (CASE 
         WHEN m.mode = 'Face to Face' THEN 1
         WHEN m.mode = 'Online' THEN 2 
         WHEN m.mode = 'RPL' THEN 5 
         ELSE 3      
    END) AS '329',
   'A6090' as '477',
    up.citizen AS '358',
    vf.maxcontribute as '392',
    vf.studentstatus as '490',
    vf.total_amount_charged as '384',
    vf.amount_paid as '381',
    vf.loan_fee as '529',
    u.chessn as '488',
    m.workexp as '337',
    '0' as '390',
    m.sumwinschool as '551',
    vf.help_debt as '558'
FROM 
    enrolment e
    INNER JOIN enrolcourse AS ec ON ec.studentid=e.enrolstudent
    INNER JOIN course AS c ON c.courseid = ec.courseid
    INNER JOIN vetfee AS  vf ON vf.userid=e.enrolstudent
    INNER JOIN users AS  u ON u.userid = e.enrolstudent
    INNER JOIN users_personal AS  up ON up.userid = e.enrolstudent
    INNER JOIN module AS m ON m.modshortname = e.enrolmod
    INNER JOIN online_intake oi ON oi.intakecode = e.online_intake
        AND STR_TO_DATE(oi.censusdate, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-09-31'
WHERE e.enrolstudent NOT LIKE '%onlinetutor%'
    AND e.enrolstudent NOT LIKE '%tes%' 
    AND e.enrolstudent NOT like '%student%'
    AND e.enrolrole = 'student' 
ORDER BY e.enrolstudent;
```

Given your posted `EXPLAIN` output, you'll also want to add the following indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE enrolment
    ADD INDEX (enrolstudent),
    ADD INDEX (enrolmod),
    ADD INDEX (online_intake);
ALTER TABLE enrolcourse
    ADD INDEX (studentid),
    ADD INDEX (courseid);
ALTER TABLE course
    ADD INDEX (courseid);
ALTER TABLE vetfee
    ADD INDEX (userid);
ALTER TABLE users
    ADD INDEX (userid);
ALTER TABLE users_personal
    ADD INDEX (userid);
ALTER TABLE module
    ADD INDEX (modshortname);
ALTER TABLE online_intake
    ADD INDEX (intakecode);
```

Comment: Hi Steve, I'd originally used a join on that too. I've swapped it back and still not completing.

Comment: Yep, just creating those now. I'll see how that goes.

Comment: @PeterKelly - I made some more tweaks to the query (eliminated another correlated subquery and eliminated a STR_TO_DATE call).  That should speed it up a little more.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I'll run those alters now. Fingers crossed they don't take too long.